# Powershell class: property vs argument naming

Tags: powershell, class, properties, arguments

In [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/uktechnet/powershell-classes) old Microsoft doc Richard Siddaway states

> I use variable names that are reminiscent of the property name. These
>   variables are arbitrary and you can use any legal variable name –
>   avoid the name of the property though!

This results in a constructor that looks like this

```
RStimezone(
   [int]$idx,
   [string]$desc,
   [string]$tmzn,
   [bool]$crnt
   ){
   $this.Index = $idx
   $this.Description = $desc
   $this.Timezone = $tmzn
   $this.Current = $crnt
}
```

But there is no explanation of WHY this naming convention is suggested. So far as I can tell there is no scopeing issue, so using arguments with the same name as the class properties should not cause issues. And to my eye this is a much more readable approach.

```
RStimezone(
   [int]$index,
   [string]$description,
   [string]$timezone,
   [bool]$current
   ){
   $this.Index = $index
   $this.Description = $description
   $this.Timezone = $timezone
   $this.Current = $current
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I would go for the more descriptive/readable variable names too. As long as you don't (mis)use [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) names, there should be no problem.

Comment: @Theo, I kind of wondered if this was basically a best practice or idiom from C#, similar to curly braces on their own lines. Good to know I am finally getting some instincts in PowerShell. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: I personally prefer descriptive parameter names, even if they happen to collide with property names - but that's not the question here :)*

I obviously can't speak for Richard, for I can think of two reasons why someone would decide to avoid method parameter names colliding with property names:

## Avoiding a future refactoring "gotcha!"

The article in question was written in September 2016!

Around that time Visual Studio Code was still in its infancy - and LSP (the Language Server Protocol) had barely been standardized.

This meant that in many editors - bar PowerShell ISE, and perhaps SAPIEN PowerShell Studio - proper and contextual "language support" for PowerShell was *purely* syntactical, and in many cases based on shoddy regex-based tokenizers.

.NET based editors *could* take advantage of the new Parser/AST API introduced in PowerShell 3.0, but this was a bit of an undertaking, since the post-3.0 language also made some syntactical allowances around implicit attribute arguments, literal array handling etc.

So by the time 5.0 came around, and the only major change to the language was the introduction of the `class` and `enum` type definition statements, very few editors were quick to implement full support for these new (and slightly complicated) features - because the rest of the language was virtually the same and many syntactical analyzers *sorta* worked.

### *What does this have to do with naming method parameters and class properties, you say?*

Well, imagine a syntactical analyzer attempting a variable-rename operation on the `$myString` parameter in the (valid) constructor below:

```bsh
class MyClass
{
    [string]
    $myString

    MyClass([string]$myString)
    {
        $this.myString = $myString
    }
}
```

A naive refactoring tool would leave you with this (invalid) constructor:

```bsh
class MyClass
{
    [string]
    $renamedString

    MyClass([string]$renamedString)
    {
        $this.myString = $renamedString
    }
}
```

## Cargo-culting

As the article by-line notes, Richard, already in 2016, had over 25 years of experience in IT, and I can assure you he's spent a significant portion of his career working with C#.

If I show you an equivalent pattern in C#, it might become obvious why this specific type of naming collision/overlap is discouraged, from a readability point-of-view:

```cs
class MyClass
{
  private string myString;

  MyClass(string myString)
  {
    this.myString = myString.Substring(Math.Min(1, myString.Length));
  }

  string SomeMethod()
  {
    return myString;
  }
}
```

In the above class, the bare token `myString` is now representing two distinct values depending on which method body you're looking at. If you think "that's not weird, I can read it just fine", take a turing test, because you might be a compiler ;-)

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen, I am revisiting this as I get deeper into refactoring for classes, and I have started on a path that may or may not have pitfalls. Basically, I don't want to have properties and arguments with identical names, but I am not thrilled with the Richard Siddaway abbreviated argument names either, from a readability standpoint. I am leaning towards an argument prefix approach, but wondering if there is a gotcha there waiting for me? So, a public property would be `[Int] $Index`, a private property would be `hidden [Int] $index` and an argument would be `[int] $_index`.

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen To my eye the underscore identifies the argument well, it's always lower case because it's always local to the method, and if it's used to set the value of a property then `$this.index = $_index` seems legible to me. So far it seems to be working without issues, and it seems to be helping with at least MY readability. Just wondering if I am going to regret this after a few thousand lines of code that uses the approach? :)

Comment: I would flip it around - `$_index` for the "private" property, `$index` for the method parameter - you get the distinction, but without imposing it on the user

Comment: Ah, interesting thought. In this case, I am the user, as the product is a self contained program, not intended for other uses. But I'm not convinced that will always be true. But I wonder, does it make any difference what the method parameter is called, since with classes you treat everything as a location parameter rather than named, anyone using my classes would not need to reference the method parameter name directly, right? If nothing else, good to know there are no surprises waiting for me if I continue down this path.

Comment: The language engine absolutely does not care - you can have a method parameter named `$Gordon` in a class with a property declared as `$Gordon`, no problem. Just do yourself a favour and be consistent in your application :) My reasoning for not prefixing with `_` is that method parameters are part of the public API surface of your class, and you shouldn't surface weird internal names

Comment: OK, I think I see it now. So a Public class parameter is $Index, a private class parameter is $_index and a method argument is $index. It "looks" weird to me to not be consistent in property names, but that's just me getting used to be consistent in public names. New habits. :)

Comment: @Gordon Old habits die hard ;-) I couldn't think of an example where I'd need both a hidden and a public version of a property with the same name, but this example might illustrate: [array wrapper/reader classes with hidden vs. public properties](https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/3802a04448c9b21a3bb31dfad6fc99c9)

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Ah, yes, I don't imagine needing identical public and private properties. I had just gotten used to anything capitalized is public, camel case is private, and I often have a mix of public and private. With luck it won't take long to get used to the new approach.